# Obtaining value in views.py from template

Tags: python, django, django-views

I've got the following code within my html template:

Template

```
<div class="submitbutton">
    <a href="{% url 'accounts:customerhomepage' %}" target="_blank" value="1">
         <button>
             View Demo
          </button>
    </a>
 </div>
```

I'd like to pass the value of 1 to the function in views.py that will render the page. Within the view, I've got the following code:

Views.py

```
demo = request.GET.get('value')
print(demo)
```

The printed result is 'None' rather than '1'. I'm not sure where my code is wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have "value" in a query string like so:

```
<a href="{% url 'accounts:customerhomepage' %}?value=1" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Any idea how I'd pass in a second value to the view such as id? Example: <a href="{% url 'accounts:customerhomepage' %}?value=1?id=1"

Comment: that would be: `<a href="{% url 'accounts:customerhomepage' %}?value=1&id=1" ...`